# TypeError: Argument 1 of Window.getDefaultComputedStyle does not implement interface Element

Tags: javascript, jquery, polymer

I have the following code outside my polymer element (in another polymer):

```
        $(mainThis.shadowRoot.querySelector('#test1')).click(function(e){
            mainThis.$.testelement.openPopup();
        });
```

The line:

```
mainThis.$.testelement.openPopup();
```

Is causing error:

```
TypeError: Argument 1 of Window.getDefaultComputedStyle does not implement interface Element.
```

openPopup - is my custom function in polymer "testelement".
The error appears only in FireFox (version 31) on other browsers (Chrome, Safari, Opera) works perfect. How to fix it ?

Edit (openPopup function):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    Polymer('popup-element', {

        domReady : function() {
            var mainThis = this;
            $(this.$.popup).on('click','.closebutton', function(e){
                mainThis.closePopup();
            });
        },
        openPopup : function (){
            $(this.$.popup).show();
            return this;
        },
        closePopup : function (){
            $(this.$.popup).hide();
            return this;
        }
    });

</script>
```

Comment: Could you paste openPopup body function ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, now I can see. I had the same problem. I have solved it like this:
Instead of:

```
$(this.$.popup).show();
```

Try this:

```
this.$.popup.style.display = "block";
```

It seems, it is impossible to use jQuery in polymer element javascript function when you execute it from another polymer element (in firefox only!). Please somebody smarter than me to improve this answer :)

Comment: I've posted the error on the Polymer github issue tracker: https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/issues/686